# Rails 4 routing error when scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffolding

After performing a `rails g scaffold Project name:string`, I get a routing error when I create a new project.

My steps: 
1) on `/projects`, I click 'New Project'.
2) I fill the project details and click 'Create Project'.
In this step the form seems to be correct:
 
`form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/projects" class="new_project" id="new_project" method="post"`
3) I get the following error (routing error): `No route matches [POST] "/projects/new"`

Whereas:
when I reload the `/projects/new` page, the creation of the project works fine

Any reason for this?

Comment: Please show the contents of `app/models/projects.rb`, `app/controllers/projects_controller.rb`, `app/views/projects/new.html.erb`, `config/routes.rb`  You're much more likely to get good help if you show us your code, otherwise we're more likely to be just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the files I have (I created most of them with the scaffolding)

app/models/project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb: (I only show here the methods that we re interested in)

```
  class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index] 
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

and config/routes.rb:

```
Testproject::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :projects
  root 'projects#index'
end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you posted a solution to your problem?

Comment: No. I don't already have a solution of my problem. I realize that it doesn't work on chrome (it sends a POST to a new action) whereas is works correctly with Safari...